# How to obtain the expected value of the following function

Tags: r, expected-value

I am trying to figure out the process I should follow to obtain the expected value of

$$
\text{CNoEst(B)} = \frac{1}{2}E(\log(1+B(|S|^2)),
$$

where $S$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance and B = 10 dB. The true value should be approximately equal o 1.15.

However, I have no clue as to the approach I should take. Also, I would love any recommendations regarding any extra material I should go through to get an understanding of these topics.

Comment: I don't think that integral can be computed analytically. Are you ok with a numerical solution?

Comment: Yes, I am okay with a numerical solution too!

Comment: Check my (numerical) answer to your question below.

Answer (score 3):

The expectation you wish to compute
$$
\frac{1}{2}E(\log(1+B(|S|^2)) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\log(1+B(|x|^2) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\text{d}x,
$$

does not seem to be computable analytically, unless $B=0$ (in which case it would be zero).

However, it can be approximated by numerical integration using `R`. Below I'm showing you the code for doing this. The code actually defines CNoEst(B) as a function of B which internally performs the numerical integration using `integrate`.

```
cnoest_b <- function(b) {
  ff= function(x) 0.5*log(1+b*(x)^2) * dnorm(x,0,1)
  ffv= Vectorize(ff, "x")
  oo = integrate(ffv, lower = -6, upper = 6)
  return(oo)
}

> cnoest_b(10)
0.8683051 with absolute error < 6.3e-05
```

As you can see from the output above, CNoEst(10) $\approx 0.8683051$, which does not coincide with your claimed value of 1.15.